# how to set the selection shadow for delegate cell in a tableview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

here is a tableview designed with delegate. I've set the selectionMode as selectRows. When I click on a row, only the central column cell with pure text shows the selection shadow while the first and last column realised by drawPixmap,drawText don't. The central is also realised by QTextDocument with code like `doc.documentLayout().draw(,)`

what to do if I want to make the row show shadow when clicking?

minimum reproducible example:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QTableView, QStyledItemDelegate, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QStandardItemModel,QStandardItem


class MyTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(2,3)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setItem(0, 0, QStandardItem('122222'))
        self.model.setItem(0, 1, QStandardItem('1'))
        self.model.setItem(1, 1, QStandardItem('1'))
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.delegate = MyDelegate()
        self.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
        

class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() == 0:
            painter.save()
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(option.rect.center(), 10,10)
            painter.restore()

        elif index.column() == 2:
            painter.save()
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setPen(Qt.red)
            painter.drawText(option.rect.center(), 'hello')
            painter.restore()
              
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = MyTableView()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the superclass method first in your item delegates paint method, then make the adjustments that you want to make.

for example:

```py
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            painter.save()
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(option.rect.center(), 10,10)
            painter.restore()
        elif index.column() == 2:
            painter.save()
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setPen(Qt.red)
            painter.drawText(option.rect.center(), 'hello')
            painter.restore()
```

---

Update

Based on information provided in the comments, you could also have the tableview's style draw the control background prior to making your own adjustments.  That way if the widget is selected then the style control will already be drawn.

for example:

```py
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        if index.column() in [0,2]:
            painter.save()
            widget = option.widget
            style = widget.style()
            style.drawControl(style.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter, widget)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            if index.column() == 0:
                painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
                painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
                painter.drawEllipse(option.rect.center(), 10,10)
            else:
                painter.setPen(Qt.red)
                painter.drawText(option.rect.center(), 'hello')
            painter.restore()
        else:
            super().paint(painter, option, index)
```

Comment: but another question arise that if the code executes the super method, some unnecessary info will be painted which will overlap with my customised painting

Comment: @arthur can you adjust your example so that the same occurs on it?

Comment: ok. I set original data in cell(0, 0) which will conflict with the painting later

Comment: @Arthur Is that information needed?

Comment: yes. Actually I load the data from database with sql model